# Passing the result of split into variables but ensure they have default values in perl

Tags: perl

In my perl program need

```
use strictures 1;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    my($action, $v1, $v2) = map { s/XX/42/g; $_ } split /\s+/;
    print "=$action=$v1=$v2=\n";
    do_someting( $action, func1($v1), func2($v2) );
}
```

the problem is, when the input contains < 3 "fields" and I want ensure than all nonexistent fields is defined and contain "DEFAULT". So want the next: input -> assigned output to variables

```
"mk aXXb ac"  -> "mk" "a42b" "ac"
"deXX ab"     -> "de42" "ab" "DEFAULT"
```

and so on..

Tried the next, but doesn't works.

```
    my($action, $v1, $v2) = map { s/XX/42/g; $_ // "DEFAULT" } split /\s+/;
```

It's looks than I'm misunderstanding how the `map` and/or the `//` operator works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` will never return `undef`, so your `//` will always return its LHS.

---

If they have different defaults,

```
my ($action, $v1, $v2) = map { s/XX/42/rg } split;
$action //= 'default action';
$v1     //= 'default v1';
$v2     //= 'default v2';
```

If it's the same default for all,

```
my ($action, $v1, $v2) = map { s/XX/42/rg } split;
$_ //= 'DEFAULT' for $action, $v1, $v2;
```

---

You could have less repetition if you used an array instead of separate vars.

If they have different defaults,

```
my @defaults = ('default action', 'default v1', 'default v2');
my @fields = map { s/XX/42/rg } split;
$fields[$_] //= $defaults[$_] for 0..2;
```

If it's the same default for all,

```
my @fields = map { s/XX/42/rg } split;
$fields[$_] //= 'DEFAULT' for 0..2;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you ask. It uses the defined-or operator `//` which was introduced in Perl 5 version 10.

```
use 5.010;

while (<>) {
  s/XX/42/g for my ($action, $v1, $v2) = map { $_ // 'DEFAULT' } ((split),(undef)x3);
  print "=$action=$v1=$v2=\n";
}
```

If you have an earlier version then this will do the same thing

```
while (<>) {
  s/XX/42/g for my ($action, $v1, $v2) = map { defined() ? $_ : 'DEFAULT' } ((split),(undef)x3);
  print "=$action=$v1=$v2=\n";
}
```